# how to add ref type as primary key in oracle?

Tags: oracle, composite-primary-key, ref

Consider the following relational schema.
Words in bold color are primary keys.

```
    branches(**bname**:char(15),city:varchar(12), phone:varchar(10))
    customers(**custno**:integer,cname:char(15),gender:char(1), bdate:date)
    accounts(**accno**:integer, branch:char(15),acctype:char(1),balance:real)
    ac(**accont:integer,customer**:integr)
```

columns in bold color are primary keys.

in ac, account and customer references account_ty and customer_ty respectively.
My problem is in ac table (account,customer) is a composite primary key. Since they are ref types, how can i add primary key in ac table.

I want to create object tables. First I created types and then tables from them.Below are my code

```
create type branch_ty as object(
bname char(15),
city varchar(12),
phone varchar(12)
)
/

create type customer_ty as object(
custno integer,
cname char(15),
gender char(1),
bdate date
)
/

create type account_ty as object(
accno integer,
branch REF branch_ty,
acctype char(1),
balance real
)
/



    create type ac_ty as object(
account REF account_ty,
customer REF customer_ty
)
/

create table branch of branch_ty(
constraint br_pk primary key(bname)
)
/

create table customers of customer_ty(
constraint cu_pk primary key(custno),
constraint cu_ch check (gender='F' or gender='M')
)
/

create table accounts of account_ty(
constraint acc_pk primary key(accno),
constraint acc_fk foreign key(branch) references branch,
constraint acc_ch check(acctype='I' or acctype='J')
)
/  

I am OK up to this point. But when I try to execute the following code segment it gives this error message.ORA-02329: column of datatype REF cannot be unique or a primary key

create table ac of ac_ty(
constraint ac_fk1 foreign key(account) references accounts,
constraint ac_fk2 foreign key(customer) references customers,
primary key(account,customer) 
)
/
Please help me. I know i can do this without using object tables.But I want to create it using object tables. Is this possible? Please help me........
```

Comment: You're leaving out some important steps.  Based on your `create table` statement, you apparently created a type `ac_ty` and you are trying to create an object table based on that type.  Post the definition of that type.  If your other tables are also object tables, post the object and table definitions.  Additionally, can you explain why you are trying to create object tables in the first place-- that's not something that is done commonly-- if you don't have a good reason, creating nice, ordinary non-object tables is almost certainly a simpler solution.

Comment: I was not aware that there is a `CREATE TABLE OF` syntax. Nor I can find any documentation for it. I know there is [`CREATE TYPE AS TABLE OF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm#i2089410) syntax.

Comment: Also, check if this helps: https://community.oracle.com/message/465754

Comment: @JustinCave First I created types for all the 4 relations.That means I have branch_ty, customer_ty, account_ty and ac_ty. Then I created tables from that types as described above. But the problem is, when I am creating the ac table I can't add (account,customer) as primary key since account is a ref type in account_ty type and customer is a ref type of customer_ty.HOw can I create the primary keys then?

Comment: @Krumia I could not find an answer from your link sir.But of course, there is a syntax  create TABLE <table name> of TYPE <type name>

Comment: @user3894236: [Off topic] I was not saying there is not such syntax, just that I was not aware about that. I would like to learn. Can you give me a link to a documentation?

Comment: @Krumia I too don't know if that syntax is available in any documentation. I am an undergraduate. Our lecturer taught the syntax.If I found any link related to that, definitely I will post the link here.

Comment: You say that you created a number of types and a number of object tables.  Post the actual DDL for these objects.  Are you saying that this is a homework assignment and that you are required to create object tables rather than building a standard data model (no one in the real world ever uses object tables)?  If your homework imposes constraints, tell us what those constraints are-- is some of the DDL that you post, for example, provided by the instructor?

Comment: I have posted the question again in detail. Can you please move to that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072375/how-to-add-ref-as-primary-key-in-oracle